# Infinite CustomScrollView scrolls back when next portion of items is presented

Tags: dart, flutter

In my app I'm using `CustomScrollView`, which should load more data when scroll position reaches the almost-end of scroll view (currently it's `position.pixels - 100.0`). The mechanism works fine, data loads as I scroll, but depending on connection speed (more precisely, on api response speed) and initial "touch down and pan up" gesture speed this bug appears. Don't know how to correctly explain it, but of the speed of scrolling was large at the moment when app starts and then finishes loading next portion of data the scroll view kind-of scrolls back in opposite direction. It looks like the scroll view "shoots off" or resists. Here's the gif with problem representation:

[image]

I've created simulation of what is happening on gif:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class ItemService {
  final _itemsController = StreamController<List<String>>();
  final _loadNextController = StreamController<bool>();

  get items => _itemsController.stream;
  get isLoadingNext => _loadNextController.stream;

  List<String> _current = [];

  loadNext() async {
    _loadNextController.add(true);
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    _current.addAll(List.generate(10, (idx) => 'Item ${_current.length + idx}'));
    _itemsController.add(_current);
    _loadNextController.add(false);
  }

  void dispose() {
    _itemsController.close();
    _loadNextController.close();
  }
}

class ItemsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ItemsScreenState createState() => _ItemsScreenState();
}

class _ItemsScreenState extends State<ItemsScreen> {
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();
  double _prevScrollPos = 0.0;

  final _service = ItemService();

  _onScroll() {
    double maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
    double currentScrollPos = _scrollController.position.pixels;
    double delta = 100.0;

    if (maxScroll - currentScrollPos <= delta && _prevScrollPos - currentScrollPos < 0) {
      _service.loadNext();

    }

    _prevScrollPos = currentScrollPos;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController.addListener(_onScroll);
    _service.loadNext();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    _service.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: CustomScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        slivers: <Widget>[
          /// navbar
          CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
            largeTitle: Text('Items'),
            automaticallyImplyTitle: false,
            previousPageTitle: 'Back',
            transitionBetweenRoutes: false,
          ),

          /// items list
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: _service.items,
            builder: (_, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final items = snapshot.data;

                return SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (_, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        height: 300.0,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                        color: index % 2 == 0
                            ? CupertinoColors.activeGreen
                            : CupertinoColors.activeOrange,
                        child: Text(items[index]),
                      );
                    },
                    childCount: items.length,
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return SliverFillRemaining(
                  child: Center(
                    child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          ),

          StreamBuilder(
            stream: _service.isLoadingNext,
            builder: (_, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data == true) {
                return SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Container(
                    // color: Colors.primary,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                    child: Center(
                      child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Container(height: 0),
                );
              }
            },
          ),

          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: SafeArea(
              child: Container(),
              bottom: true,
              top: false,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

main() {
  runApp(CupertinoApp(
    home: ItemsScreen(),
  ));
}
```

UPDATE: kind-of resolved this issue by calling `_scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.pixels);` after `_service.loadNext()`

Comment: I think your problem is sort of caused by the ```BouncingScrollPhysics```. Technically the scroll reaches to the end before new content is loaded, and then it bounce back, then the content is loaded. Two fast options would be to remove the ```BouncingScrollPhysics``` or trigger the ```loadMore``` faster.

Comment: @danypata removed `BouncingScrollPhysics`, behavior is the same. Also, unfortunately, `loadMore` is an async operation and I cannot control its’ speed. I've tried calling it faster by штскуыштп `delta`, but it doesn't help a lot. If I, let’s say, implement custom scroll physics, would it potentially resolve this problem?

Comment: There might be a problem with ```SliverList``` here, I think the ```SliverList``` is computing the scroll offset in a bad way. Did you try to replace it with a ```ListView.builder(...)``` ?

Comment: @danypata will try it now

Comment: @danypata meh, same thing. And it looks kinda laggy, if I use ListView inside of CustomScrollView

Comment: That was "increasing" word instead of "штскуыштп" in second comment

Answer (score 0):

Just add `ClampingScrollPhysics()` on CustomScrollView to remove the bounce physics.

```dart
CustomScrollView(
  physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),  // Remove bounce physics
  controller: _scrollController,
  slivers: <Widget>[
    /// navbar
    const CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(...)
  ],
),
```